# Best All-In-One monitor

Tags: gaming, monitors

I need a monitor for programming, and light gaming. With a price at about 250 euros which is ~290$. My requirements are:

-23.8"-25"

-1080p/1200p

-very thin bezels

I'm deciding between Dell S2415 and Dell U2414H. I would like if you would tell me any other monitors that fit those requirements or help me decide between those 2.

Comment: Regarding light gaming: would high refresh or G/Freesync be important to you? I'm guessing that color reproduction or viewing angles aren't too important.

Comment: They are important but I could live without them, for e.g. if you recommend me 2 similar monitors and 1 haves G sync/ freesync I'll take one with G/Free Sync

Comment: What GPU are you using? Would you be willing to switch in order to get G/Freesync?

Comment: R9 380 4GB STRIX GAMING, probably not, but again I just need a thin bezel 25" monitor, and I believe that even without Gsync/freesync, games that I play(mostly 3rd person shooters like GTA, Sleeping Dogs, Watch Dogs, some Far Cry and sport games) will run great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR: The [LG 24MP59G-P](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-24MP59G-P-gaming-monitor)/[LG 24MP59HT-P](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-24MP59HT-P-led-monitor)

€250<sup>1</sup> is a pretty massive budget for a monitor of that size and resolution. At this price point, I'd consider decent color (read: IPS) non-negotiable. Since you mentioned gaming and programming (not content creation), I'm guessing perfect color isn't too important though. For that reason, I focused on providing a better gaming experience.

With both of these monitors, you get a 75Hz refresh rate with Freesync. IMO, these features make gaming (even relatively casual gaming) much, much better.

Beyond that, compared to the Dell monitors you suggested:

- ≈€30 cheaper (about [€125](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/Dnbkcf/lg-24mp59g-p-238-1920x1080-75hz-monitor-24mp59g-p))
- Slightly thicker bezels
- Slightly worse out-of-the-box calibration
- Some backlight bleed
- Fewer creature comforts
- (Monitor-dependent) No built-in speakers or USB hub

Given how much room you have left in your budget, it should be within your budget to get a nice USB hub and set of bookshelf speakers.

Between the G and HT models, the difference appears to be in vendors (BestBuy carries only the HT, the G is carried more universally) and inputs (the HT has 2x HDMI and 1x VGA, the G has 1x DisplayPort, 1x HDMI, and 1x VGA.) I'd recommend the G if you can find it (DisplayPort tends to have fewer issues with Freesync.)

1. I don't know know where you live or what actual prices are as a result, so I'll be using USD and converting.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 monitors are pretty quality products but I can recommend you a few more. If you want to buy a 24-25" monitor for both gaming and programming, you may think

- ASUS PB238Q (23")
- Acer R240HY bidx (23.8")
- HP Pavilion 22cwa (21.5")

All of them have very thin bezels and cheaper then 250 Euros. If you tell me about your gaming setup, I can recommend a few more. You may [check this guide for choosing a programming monitor](https://www.slothygeek.com/best-monitor-for-programming/).

Comment: Please try to limit your answers to one recommendation. That way, you can give the OP as much info about them as possible and it also allows the community to vote for the best monitor.

Comment: @Erdem Ugurluol "If you tell me about your gaming setup" did you mean my specs or what games will I play on my monitor? If games are the case then pretty much PES 18, Civ VI, horror games like The Evil Within 2, NFS.. So more or less casual games - no FPS games